# JavaScript Presentation/Deck

Tags: javascript, presentation

I've been to a couple of talks recently where the speaker had a presentation/deck with a live code window and a console output.  I've got to do a JS presentation and I thought it would be really useful to do live code.

Does anyone know any apps I can use for this? Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is the right place to post this as it's quite easy to find on the internet as well and it's not a programming question which is what SO is for, a quick google will give you the answer - pretty sure ;)

Comment: Please re-ask your question at [Software recommendations Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), I believe that is a better place for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many options:

https://jsfiddle.net/

http://js.do/

http://jsbin.com/

https://repl.it/languages/JavaScript

Finally... https://www.google.com/search?q=online+javascript+sandbox

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).